# How to build instance of Emacs to run on an x86_64 system different from the one it was built on?

Tags: cross-compilation, static-linking

I want to build the latest version of Emacs (from `git.sv.gnu.org`) for a CentOS system, but the building must be done on a Debian system<sup>1</sup>.  Both systems run on x86_64 architectures.

I've seen instructions for doing this sort of thing before, but now that I need them, I can't find them (i.e., I have not found the right keywords for my Google searches).

I can't find the instructions I'm looking in [the installation info for Emacs](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/INSTALL), either.  Again, this could also be due to a faulty search strategy, but it occurred to me that maybe the reason I'm not finding this info is that it is simply generic Unix knowledge (like, e.g., unpacking a tar ball, or changing the ownership of the unpacked contents), not specific to Emacs.  Hence, I'm posting the question here.

To recap, my goal is to create a self-contained Emacs executable that does not require any libraries from its host system.

What settings must I use to compile Emacs to achieve this goal?  More specifically, how would I have to change the following sequence

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=${INSTALL_DIR} --with--m17n-flt
./make bootstrap
./make install
```

...to do this?

For what it's worth, in the "build" (Debian) system, `cc` is symlinked to `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>It's a long story, but basically, I have root access in the Debian system, but not in the CentOS one.</sup>

Comment: Use flatpak/appimage/snap. Much easier than a static compile.

Comment: @IporSircer: Thank you for the pointer.  Maybe for someone familiar with those tools they would indeed be easier than a static compile.  For me, however, I'm skeptical.  I'd never heard of them before, so I would have to learn to use one of them before I could put in practice your suggestion.

Comment: @IporSircer: I stand corrected.  I found this https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnu.emacs .  It looks like now my problem reduces to installing `flatpak` on the target system, as a non-root user...

Comment: why do you need to be root in order to build emacs? also, building it with eg. `--prefix=/your/home/emacs` and just copying the whole thing over may just work (or it will easily fixable by copying the couple of missing libs somewhere and using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- again, no need to be root for that).

Comment: @mosvy: because that would require building *all* of Emacs bazillion dependencies from source.  *Have you ever tried it?*  It is a far cry from `apt-get install emacs`.  I was at it for a couple of days, and had to give up...

Comment: @IporSircer: I was wrong once more.  The flatpak download I linked before is for version 26.1 of Emacs.  It looks like I would have to create my own flatpak, after all...

Comment: Not only I have tried it, I **did** it. Also, if emacs doesn't find a lib on the target system (check with `ldd`), you can just copy it over somewhere and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point it to it.

Comment: @mosvy: well, I was not able to do it in the system I'm working on.  I suppose you will understand that it all depends on how many Emacs dependencies are already available in the system one is building for, and why it would be a problem if very many of them are missing and one needs to install all of them from source.

Answer (score 1):

The way to create a statically-linked binary is to pass the `-static` option to the linker. Since you don't run the linker directly, you'll need to get that through the build system (and probably through the compiler, too).

Emacs is a GNU package, so it probably uses autotools for its build. In that case, you need to use the `LDFLAGS` variable:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-static"
```

Unfortunately, upon trying this out, I found that emacs uses a number of `glibc` function calls that don't work in static binaries; and the "bootstrap-emacs" which is built as part of that will even segfault at startup because of it. So you can't do it with a static build.

Instead, you could do one of the following:

- You set up a CentOS chroot on your Debian box in which you do the build, and then copy the binaries to the CentOS chroot
- You can build an autotools package with an alternative prefix, so it works from your home directory:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/emacs --exec-prefix=$HOME/bin
  ```

  This will compile emacs so that it installs in `$HOME/bin`, with any support files found under `$HOME/emacs`. Of course, that assumes that the required libraries are available on the CentOS machine, which might not be the case.
- You can just *ask* your local root to install emacs for you...